# Method Invocation Type inference in JLS

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, jls

Consider the following article in JLS:9 ([18.5.2.2. Additional Argument Constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.2.2))

- Here while adding actual arguments to form the set of Constraints - after the Type Parameters have been Reduced and Incorporated - we have the following clause:

> Let θ be the substitution [P1:=α1, ..., Pp:=αp] defined in §18.5.1 to replace the type parameters of m with inference variables.
> Then, for all i (1 ≤ i ≤ k):
> If ei is not pertinent to applicability, C contains ‹ei → Fi θ›.

Clearly - when determining the "Invocation Applicability" the actual arguments expressions supplied are tested if they are "Pertinent to Applicabilility" and the Constraint set is being reduced and resolved and merged with the bound set.

**My question is - that when we are trying to infer the "Invocation Type" why are actual argument expressions `ei` included in the set of valid constraints only when  they are "not pertinent to applicability"?**

Comment: Link  it next time please :)

Comment: Not a leading question, but did you read the definition of ["pertinent to applicability"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.2)? What is your understanding of it?

Comment: I guess a hand-wavey and oversimplified explanation is that non-pertinent-to-applicability expressions are mostly lambdas (and compound expressions containing lambdas), and lambdas are expressions whose type is often inferred. You can't really use an expression whose type must be inferred to infer what method it applies to. There's a circular reasoning about that, which is why it's a special case.

Comment: @Michael : But then why are only "non-pertinent" elements included in the constraint set determination and not the "pertinent" expressions ? - your point it right that "You can't really use an expression whose type must be inferred to infer what method it applies to." - that is what I want to know exactly that why is it included in invocation type determination - but not in the applicability determination - but the "pertinent-to-applicability" excluded from invocation type determination?

Comment: "*But then why are **only** "non-pertinent" elements included in the constraint set determination*" That's not what it says. You're not reading the whole thing. "*Additional constraints may be included, depending on the form of ei*"

Comment: Indeed - the additional constraints may be on throws clauses or conditional expressions etc - but in the current question I am referring to the basic constraint that gets added in the set "C" ‹ei → Fi θ›"